# Deserializing inner structure to string with JavaScriptSerializer in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, json, javascriptserializer

I am using the `JavaScriptSerializer` in .NET to deserialize structures which can be your standard flat key/value pair like this:

```
{
    "Value": 3.14,
    "Type": "Real"
}
```

Or more complex, with an inner hierarchical value object like this:

```
{
    "Value": { "something": "test" },
    "Type": "JsonData"
}
```

The problem I have is that in the case of `"Type": "JsonData"`, the object can be arbitrary. I can't make any assumption as to what its structure will be.

However, the "upper layers" of my application will know what to do with this data.

I thus need to figure out a way to keep the **Value** field a string, no matter if it contains an integer, a string, or a complete JSON structure. Basically, I don't want the `JavaScriptSerializer` to parse anything in there. I would love to be able to have such a class:

```
public class JsonObject
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

With `Value` containing the unprocessed, vanilla value that was in my JSON.

**Is there any way to tell .NET to NOT to parse some part of my JSON?**

Please *do not suggest using another library like JSON.NET*. I know it would probably be capable of doing this, but this is for a project which will be distributed as a library -- This is why I'd rather have my library depend only on the standard .NET framework.

Comment: I must say **JSON.Net** is the best `json` parsing library available.

Comment: I know and I've used it many times in many other projects :) However it's completely overkill for my project and I really must do with what the standard .NET runtime provides and nothing more!

Comment: ASP.NET MVC *also* uses Json.Net, this should address the requirement. The "as a library" requirement doesn't mean that you can't use Json.NET. It's not overkill, it's simpler, easier, more compliant than the obsolete JavaScriptSerializer.

Comment: Besides, *what* is the problem? Can't you simply deserialize to the type you provided? What have you tried and what is the issue?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos "The problem I have is that in the case of "Type": "JsonData", the object can be arbitrary. I can't make any assumption as to what its structure will be."

Comment: @NikhilV the OP said he'd like to use a class where `Type` is a string - why not use such a class then? [Deserialize<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355316(v=vs.110).aspx) accepts a target type

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What do you suggest I specify as a type in `Deserialize<T>` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an attribute to instruct the `JavaScriptSerializer` not to parse a particular JSON property (other than to completely ignore it, which is not what you want).  However, you could make a `JavaScriptConverter` which would effectively re-serialize the property in question such that you still get the result you want: all the values end up as strings.

Here is what the converter might look like:

```
public class JsonObjectConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get { return new List<Type> { typeof(JsonObject) }; }
    }

    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
        obj.Type = (string)dictionary["Type"];
        obj.Value = serializer.Serialize(dictionary["Value"]);
        return obj;
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(object obj, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To use the converter, you must register it with the `JavaScriptSerializer` using the `RegisterConverters` method.  Here is a demo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"
        [
            {
                ""Value"" : ""foo bar"",
                ""Type"" : ""String""
            },
            {
                ""Value"" : 3.14,
                ""Type"" : ""Real""
            },
            {
                ""Value"" : 
                {
                    ""Something"" : ""Test"",
                    ""Items"" : [""A"", ""B"", ""C""]
                },
                ""Type"" : ""JsonData""
            },
            {
                ""Value"" : 42,
                ""Type"" : ""Integer""
            }
        ]";

        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        jss.RegisterConverters(new List<JavaScriptConverter> { new JsonObjectConverter() });

        List<JsonObject> list = jss.Deserialize<List<JsonObject>>(json);
        foreach (JsonObject item in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("({0}) {1}", item.Type, item.Value));
        }
    }
}

public class JsonObject
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
(String) "foo bar"
(Real) 3.14
(JsonData) {"Something":"Test","Items":["A","B","C"]}
(Integer) 42
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! During this time I decided to -re-serialize like you suggested. Without the converter though. Your solution is a bit cleaner though!

Answer (score 0):

try with this :

```
public class JsonObject
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public object Type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already tried it and yes it deserializes correctly. However, the problem I have is that I *really* need ``Value`` to be a string and not an ``object``. This is what the upper parts of my code expect!

Comment: your requirement is kind of weird. Plus `with "Value": 3.14`, `Value` isn't a `string`.

Comment: I know it's not a string. What I'm saying is that the upper layers will know what to do with ``"3.14"`` or  ``"\"Hello\""``

Comment: well then, they might be aware of `object` too.